# Insert every picture of subfolder and type subfolder name as a heading1 in blank pages

Tags: vba, ms-word, insert-image

Under this path {c:\testbatpic} ,there are many folders，such as name is  abc, def,ghi ... n,
under abc subfolder ,there are a lot of images, such as , 1.jpg,2.jpg ... n.jpg or png files.
many subfolder included many images.
how to  type subfolder name with a "heading1"style,in blank pages,and insert every picture of subfolder?
Here is some code,but how modify these code to meet my idea?

```
Sub loopAllSubFolderSelectStartDirectory()
 Dim FSOLibrary As FileSystemObject
 Dim FSOFolder As Object
 Dim folderName As String

 folderName = "C:\testbatpic"

 Set FSOLibrary = New FileSystemObject

 LoopAllSubFolders FSOLibrary.getfolder(folderName)

End Sub

Sub LoopAllSubFolders(FSOFolder As Object)

 Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
 Dim FSOFile As Object

 For Each FSOSubFolder In FSOFolder.subfolders
     LoopAllSubFolders FSOSubFolder
     With Selection
     .Range.Text = Chr(13) & FSOSubFolder.name
 End With
Next

For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files
 ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture (FSOFile.path)
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub InsertMulti_pic_with_subfoldername()
 'To traversal every subfolder under path，then print out subfolder name on 
 'word，after insert all picture  2022.09.21 by Dagang
    Dim FSOLibrary As Object                                          
    Dim FSOFolder As Object
    Dim folderName As String
    folderName = "D:\desktop folder\pic\"             
    Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    LoopAllSubFolders FSOLibrary.GetFolder(folderName)               
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete                        
End Sub
Sub LoopAllSubFolders(FSOFolder As Object)
    Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
    Dim FSOFile As Object
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Set rng = Selection.Range
  For Each FSOSubFolder In FSOFolder.subfolders                       
      With Selection                                                   
           rng.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.End                     
           .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak                             
            rng.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.End                     
           .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
           .EndKey unit:=wdStory
           rng.Text = FSOSubFolder.name
              Set rng = rng.Paragraphs(1).Range                        
                  rng.style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1       
                  rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
     End With
     LoopAllSubFolders FSOSubFolder                                      
  Next

  For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files                                     
      Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture (FSOFile.path)                    
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).